How to make a file permanently available (open) when I close and reopen vscode?
Suppose I want some file to be always open no matter what project I open with VSCode.
I can pin it, yes, but, after I load a different project, the file is gone.
I need some files to be persistent no matter what I open in VSCode,
just like in Sublime Text.
Is it possible?

This question is similar to: Is it possible the prevent VS-Code from closing a file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, my question is different. A pinned tab remains open if it was pinned within a specific workspace. But when I open another workspace, it's gone. What I want is for it to always remain, no matter what workspace I open.
